Firebase doTransaction setValue of data class changes the members names
I'm using runTransaction method in my Android app as follows:
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun sendTableMsg(move: PokerTableMsg?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "sendTableMsg $move")
    this.mMessage = move
    mTableMessagesRef.runTransaction(this)
}

override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
    Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction /S$mTurnCounter - $mMessage")
    mutableData.child("/S$mTurnCounter").value = mMessage
    return Transaction.success(mutableData)
}

and I'm getting the data in different place.
Although the data class is:
data class PokerTableMsg(
    val turnIndex: UInt = 0u,
    val userState: UInt = UserState.INVALID.value,
    val minRaise: UInt = 0u
)

but in the firebase terminal it looks like that:

Why is it adding the -pVg5ArA suffix to each member?

What exactly does this line Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction /S$mTurnCounter - $mMessage") print?

doTransaction /S0 - PokerTableMsg(turnIndex=1, userState=1, minRaise=0)

Do you have any active cloud function that performs sone updates?

Actually the answer is interesting, the problem is that firebase can not find properties to serialize in class kotlin.UInt. I tried to change doTransaction to:
override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): 
Transaction.Result {
    Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction - S$mTurnCounter - $mMessage")
    val message = mapOf(
        MIN_RAISE_KEY to mMessage.minRaise,
        TURN_IDX_KEY to mMessage.turnIndex,
        USER_STATE_KEY to mMessage.userState
        )
    mutableData.child("S$mTurnCounter").value = message
    return Transaction.success(mutableData)
}

and got:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: User code called from the Firebase Database runloop threw an exception:
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class kotlin.UInt

I think it's a bug in firebase way of parsing data classs with members of type kotlin.UInt.
I changed doTransaction back to:
override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): 
Transaction.Result {
    Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction - S$mTurnCounter - $mMessage")
    mutableData.child("S$mTurnCounter").value = mMessage
    return Transaction.success(mutableData)
}

and PokerTableMsg to:
data class PokerTableMsg(
val turnIndex: Int = 0,
val userState: Int = UserState.INVALID.value,
val minRaise: Int = 0
)

And it fixed it.
